# Как сделать blur для background без javascript

Tags: css, blur

[image: blur background]

Приветствую.
Не могу найти КАК сделать так чтобы фон был размытым с помощью css,предполагаю, что красиво средствами css это пока невозможно.

На примере блок из 6 модулей.

1. Хотел применить размытие для бэкграунда, при наведении размытие
   (filter:blur) исчезает, бордовая полупрозрачная заливка это :before,
   если применить размытие к классу, то размоется и псевдо :before или
   :after, а мне это не подходит. Нужно размытие только фона. Как это сделать?(без javascript)
2. Во втором блоке я решил попробовать добавить блок внутрь блока, и добавленному блоку сделать размытие бэкграунда. Пока не знаю как это применить при эффекте :hover
3. В третьем случае я сделал :after с текстом и :before с размытым фоном.
   Так же пока не понятно как это применить к :hover

```css
body{margin:0;padding:0;}
.portfolio{
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:50px;
  width:100%;
  min-height:450px;
  background:#ccc;
   display:grid;
          grid-template-columns:200px 200px 200px;
          grid-template-areas:
            "cell-1 cell-2 cell-3"
            "cell-4 cell-5 cell-6";
          grid-template-rows:200px 200px;
          justify-content:center;/*вырванивание блоков по центру*/
          align-content: center;/*прижимает блоки друг к другу*/
}
.cell{
  width:200px;
  /height:200px;/*включить если не указывать количество и высоту строк*/
  background:pink;
  border:1px solid #444;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.cell{margin-top:-1px;}
.cell-1{grid-are:cell-1;}
.cell-2{grid-area:cell-2;}
.cell-3{grid-area:cell-3;}
.cell-4{grid-area:cell-4;}
.cell-5{grid-area:cell-5;}
.cell-6{grid-area:cell-6;}
@media screen and (max-width:640px){
  .portfolio{
    padding:20px 0;
    grid-template-columns:200px 200px;
    justify-content:center;/*вырванивание блоков по центру*/
    grid-template-rows:repeat(3,200px);
    grid-template-areas:
      "cell-1 cell-2"
      "cell-3 cell-4"
      "cell-5 cell-6";
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:418px){
  .portfolio{
    padding:20px 0;
    justify-content:center;/*вырванивание блоков по центру*/
    grid-template-columns:200px;
    grid-template-rows:repeat(6,200px);
    grid-template-areas:
      "cell-1" 
      "cell-2"
      "cell-3" 
      "cell-4"
      "cell-5" 
      "cell-6";
  }
}
/*position end-----------------------*/

.cell{
    background:
    /*linear-gradient(/-----------------фон для текста внизу/
      to bottom, 
      transparent 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 80%),*/
    url(http://vic4884g.bget.ru/img/421H.jpg) 
    no-repeat center;
    background-size:cover;
}
/*cell-1-------------------------------*/
.cell-1{-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);}
.cell-1:before{
  content:"some text";
  font-size:30px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:80px;/*сдвигает текст*/
  font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:rgba(178, 48, 48,0.5);
  }
/*------------------cell-2*/
.blur{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:
    url(http://vic4884g.bget.ru/img/433H.jpg) 
    no-repeat center;
  background-size:cover;
  filter:blur(2px);
}
.cell-2:after{
  content:"some text";
  font-size:30px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:80px;/*сдвигает текст*/
  font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:rgba(178, 48, 48,0.5);
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  }
/*cell-3----------------------------------------*/
.cell-3:after{
  content:"some text";
  font-size:30px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:80px;/*сдвигает текст*/
  font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  left:0px;
  }
.cell-3:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:
    url(http://vic4884g.bget.ru/img/421H.jpg) 
    no-repeat center;
  background-size:cover;
  filter:blur(5px);
  }
/*
:before
overflow:hidde;
transition:1s;
:not(:hover)
*/
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="portfolio">
  <div class="cell cell-1">1</div>
  <div class="cell cell-2"><div class="blur">2</div></div>
  <div class="cell cell-3">3</div>
  <div class="cell cell-4">4</div>
  <div class="cell cell-5">5</div>
  <div class="cell cell-6">6</div>
</div><!-- portfolio -->
  </div><!-- wrap -->
```

Comment: Вы покажите, какого эффекта вы хотите достичь в итоге? По текстовому описанию не понятно. Лучше один раз увидеть, чем сто раз услышать)

Comment: java и javascript два разных языка, исправьте ошибку в заголовке...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: white;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 111;
}

#foto {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEVtQ.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  filter: blur(10px);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#wrapper:hover #foto {
  filter: blur(0);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <p>FOTO
    <P>
      <div id="foto">

      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, наверное так и сделаю. *кто-то исправил заголовок =)

Comment: @VictorKas java и javascript разные языки, поэтому поправил

Comment: Вместо спасибо, можно было бы и ответ принять)))))

Comment: это первый мой пост, не опытный) но я нажал потом "принять" =)

Comment: не нажал))))))))

Comment: я извиняюсь, но куда тогда тыкать? я что-то запутался тут слегка =(

Comment: галочка рядом с вопросом

Comment: тьфу, а я ищу) +

Answer (score 2):

пока эксперементировал получилось несколько интересных эффектов с :hover (smooth)
выкладываю, может кому пригодится

```css
body{margin:0;padding:0;}
.portfolio{
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:50px;
  width:100%;
  min-height:450px;
  background:#ccc;
   display:grid;
          grid-template-columns:200px 200px 200px;
          grid-template-areas:
            "cell-1 cell-2 cell-3"
            "cell-4 cell-5 cell-6";
          grid-template-rows:200px 200px;
          justify-content:center;/*вырванивание блоков по центру*/
          align-content: center;/*прижимает блоки друг к другу*/
}
.cell{
  width:200px;
  /height:200px;/*включить если не указывать количество и высоту строк*/
  background:pink;
  border:1px solid #444;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.cell{margin-top:-1px;}
.cell-1{grid-are:cell-1;}
.cell-2{grid-area:cell-2;}
.cell-3{grid-area:cell-3;}
.cell-4{grid-area:cell-4;}
.cell-5{grid-area:cell-5;}
.cell-6{grid-area:cell-6;}
@media screen and (max-width:640px){
  .portfolio{
    padding:20px 0;
    grid-template-columns:200px 200px;
    justify-content:center;/*вырванивание блоков по центру*/
    grid-template-rows:repeat(3,200px);
    grid-template-areas:
      "cell-1 cell-2"
      "cell-3 cell-4"
      "cell-5 cell-6";
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:418px){
  .portfolio{
    padding:20px 0;
    justify-content:center;/*вырванивание блоков по центру*/
    grid-template-columns:200px;
    grid-template-rows:repeat(6,200px);
    grid-template-areas:
      "cell-1" 
      "cell-2"
      "cell-3" 
      "cell-4"
      "cell-5" 
      "cell-6";
  }
}
/*position end-----------------------*/

.cell{
    background:
    /*linear-gradient(/-----------------фон для текста внизу/
      to bottom, 
      transparent 80%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 80%),*/
    url(http://vic4884g.bget.ru/img/421H.jpg) 
    no-repeat center;
    background-size:cover;
 
}
/*cell-1-------------------------------*/
.cell-1{z-index:0;}
.cell-1:hover{z-index:20;}
.cell-1:before{
  content:"some text";
  font-size:30px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:80px;/*сдвигает текст*/
  font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:rgba(178, 48, 48,0.5);
  left:0;
  top:0;
  }
.cell-1:hover:before{transition:0.5s;top:200px;left:200px;}
.cell-1:not(:hover):before{transition:0.5s;}
.cell-1:focus:before{transition:0.5s;top:200px;left:200px;}
.cell-1:not(:focus):before{transition:0.5s;}

/*------------------cell-2*/
.cell-2:after{
  content:"some text";
  font-size:30px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:80px;/*сдвигает текст*/
  font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:rgba(178, 48, 48,0.5);
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  z-index:10;
  opacity:1;
  }
.cell-2:hover:after{transition: 0.5s; opacity:0;z-index:-1;}
.cell-2:not(:hover):after{transition: 0.5s;filter:}

/*cell-3----------------------------------------*/
.cell-3:after{
  content:"some text";
  font-size:30px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:80px;/*сдвигает текст*/
  font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  }
.cell-3:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:
    url(http://vic4884g.bget.ru/img/421H.jpg) 
    no-repeat center;
  background-size:cover;
  filter:blur(5px);
  left:0px;
  }
.cell-3:hover:after{bottom:200px;transition:0.5s;}
.cell-3:not(:hover):after{transition:0.5s;}
.cell-3:hover:before{top:200px;opacity:0;transition:0.5s;}
.cell-3:not(:hover):before{transition:0.3s;}
/*cell-4----------------------------------------*/
.cell-4:after{
  content:"smooth effect";
  font-size:30px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:70px;/*сдвигает текст*/
  font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  left:0px;
  z-index:0;
  }
.cell-4:hover:after{left:200px;transition:0.5s;}
.cell-4:not(:hover):after{transition:0.5s;}
.cell-4:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:210px;
  height:210px;
  left:-5px;
  opacity:1;
  background:
    url(http://vic4884g.bget.ru/img/421H.jpg) 
    no-repeat center;
  background-size:cover;
  filter:blur(5px);
  }
.cell-4:hover:before{left:200px;opacity:0;transition:0.8s;}
.cell-4:not(:hover):before{transition:0.5s;}

/*------------------------------------------------cell-5*/
.cell-5:after{
  content:"smooth effect";
  font-size:30px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:70px;/*сдвигает текст*/
  font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  }
.cell-5:hover:after{top:200px;transition:0.5s;}
.cell-5:not(:hover):after{transition:0.5s;}
.cell-5:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:210px;
  height:210px;
  left:-5px;
  top:0;
  opacity:1;
  background:
    url(http://vic4884g.bget.ru/img/421H.jpg) 
    no-repeat center;
  background-size:cover;
  filter:blur(5px);
  }
.cell-5:hover:before{top:200px;opacity:0;transition:0.1s;}
.cell-5:not(:hover):before{transition:0.3s;}
/*---------------------------cell-6*/
.cell-6:after{
  content:"some text";
  font-size:30px;
  color:#444;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:80px;/*сдвигает текст*/
  font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  font-weight:bold;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  z-index:10;
  opacity:1;
  }
.cell-6:before{
  content:" ";
  font-size:30px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  position:absolute;
  width:210px;
  height:210px;
   background:
    url(http://vic4884g.bget.ru/img/421H.jpg) 
    no-repeat center;
  background-size:cover;
  left:-5px;
  top:-5px;
  z-index:9;
  filter:blur(5px);
  }
.cell-6:hover:after{transition: 0.5s; opacity:0;z-index:-1;}
.cell-6:not(:hover):after{transition: 0.5s;filter:}
.cell-6:hover:before{transition: 0.5s; opacity:0;z-index:-2;}
.cell-6:not(:hover):before{transition: 0.5s;filter:}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="portfolio">
  <div class="cell cell-1">1</div>
  <div class="cell cell-2"><div class="blur">2</div></div>
  <div class="cell cell-3">3</div>
  <div class="cell cell-4"><span>smooth effect with in left side</span></div>
  <div class="cell cell-5">5</div>
  <div class="cell cell-6">6</div>
</div><!-- portfolio -->
  </div><!-- wrap -->
```